# Time triggger azure function is deleted from azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created a azure function app and added three azure functions and deployed these functions using visual studio publish profile. these functions worked for me around one month. after that these function deleted from azure function automatically. now I am trying to re-create function but it is not working. I have consumption plan .could you please help me what reason for this issue and how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

When we create an Azure Function App, it will  create  an Azure Storage Account where the content (code, json, etc…), required to run the Azure Functions are to be stored.

- If choosing the **Consumption hosting plan**, your content is stored in Azure Files.
- If choosing the **Dedicated / App Service plan**, your content is stored in an Azure Storage Container.
- *Upon creation of the Azure Function App, the storage container is created for you and stored in a Application Setting for the Azure Function App named: **WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE**.
- *Upon creation of the Azure Function App the Azure Storage Account endpoint is generated and stored in an Application Setting named: **WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING**

**Note**: Do not change or modify the below :

**WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE** and **WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING**.

Do not navigate to the Storage Account blade in the portal and **reconfigure** or **remove** the Storage Account or Storage Container.

Doing either of those things will result in the deletion of functions in function app.

You can follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908553/deleting-azure-function-published-by-visual-studio), to delete the azure function  published by Visual Studio and try publishing again.